# Bind9 IP update

Tags: linux, dns, domain, bind

I have 2 DNS servers (BIND9) (primary, secondary) and 1 domain. I have a webserver with dynamic IP. So if my IP changed I can't reach my site over domain, because in the DNS servers the domain zone IP cot changed.

My question is: How can I update my zone from my server with my public IP address every x time? Can somebody give me an updater script over Linux (Debian 9)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RFC 2136 "DNS UPDATE", either by scripting the `nsupdate` tool or by using a compatible third-party client:

#### Shared secret key (TSIG)

1. Generate a secret key for authenticating the updates:

   ```
   $ tsig-keygen -r /dev/urandom | tee tsig-key.private
   key "tsig-key" {
       algorithm hmac-sha256;
       secret "7P6HbRZRJCmtauo/lV0jwN9wkMgBTUikhf9JuaTvYT4=";
   };
   ```

   This key is known to the server and client, and nobody else.
2. Copy the printed text into your `named.conf`. (You can have multiple keys for different hosts, each with a unique name in the `key "…"` field.)
3. Enable dynamic updates in the zone configuration:

   ```
   zone … {
       …
       update-policy {
           /* grant <key_name> <policy> <record_types> */
           grant "tsig-key" name myserver.example.com ANY;
       };
   };
   ```

   Various different policies can be used; e.g. `zonesub` allows updating the *entire* zone, and `subdomain dyn.example.com` has the obvious meaning.
4. Perform updates:

   ```
   $ nsupdate -k tsig-key.private
   > zone example.com
   > del myserver.example.com
   > add myserver.example.com 3600 A 100.64.1.1
   > send
   ```

There are various clients capable of automatic updates.

#### Public/private key (SIG(0))

1. Generate a key pair:

   ```
   $ dnssec-keygen -r /dev/urandom -T KEY -n USER myclient.example.com
   $ ls K*
   Kmyclient.example.com.+005+07399.key
   Kmyclient.example.com.+005+07399.private
   ```
2. The `*.key` file contains the public key – add it to your DNS zone.

   The `*.private` file contains the private key – copy it to the client computer. (Actually, copy *both* files to the client computer.)
3. Set up `update-policy { }` in exactly the same way as with TSIG.
4. Perform updates also in the same way using `nsupdate -k <filename>.private`.

(Note: While TSIG key names are arbitrary, SIG(0) keys are stored in DNS and therefore always named like hostnames/subdomains. The key name *does not* need to match the hostname you're updating, though.)

#### Kerberos (GSS-TSIG)

A bit out of scope, but BIND9 supports this as well (mainly for use with Active Directory).

Comment: The "compatible third-party client" can be [ddnsupdate](https://ente.limmat.ch/ftp/pub/software/bash/ddnsupdate/ddnsupdate) bash script. Follow the instructions in the [README](https://ente.limmat.ch/ftp/pub/software/bash/ddnsupdate/README).